# Multiple-Weighted Graph Elimination

Tags: c, database, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have a multiple weighted graph. Each between nodes are showing the paths from a city to another city and each edge have a time, distance and cost. The user should enter a start and an end point and a criteria for the path (time, distance, and cost). Once the program get this,it should traverse and remove redundant nodes between a current node and the next while traversing from Starting Node to the Ending Node based on the criteria chosen. Here, a redundant node means that the second or the third connection to the **same next** node to reach to the final node with worse values. Here, worse means longer time, more costly, or longer distance.
I have tried different methods like converting to a simple one-weighted graph, using Dijkstra and using arrays for storing the edge values but non of them give me the desired output. Can you suggest me the most time and space efficient algorithm to do this task?
this is one of the codes I have written. This code works for path from 1-4 but for the other paths, it shows the wrong result and while debugging I understand that the problem is related to the current and next_vertex value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_VERTICES 40

enum color { White, Gray, Black };

typedef struct list_node {
    int index;
    int time;
    int distance;
    int cost;
    struct list_node* next;
} list_node;

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    enum color color;
    list_node* head;
} node;

typedef struct graph {
    int nVertices;
    node heads[];
} graph;

node* new_node(int data) {
    node* z = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    z->data = data;
    z->head = NULL;
    z->color = White;
    return z;
}

list_node* new_list_node(int item_index, int time, int distance, int cost) {
    list_node* z = (list_node*)malloc(sizeof(list_node));
    z->index = item_index;
    z->time = time;
    z->distance = distance;
    z->cost = cost;
    z->next = NULL;
    return z;
}

graph* new_graph(int nVertices) {
    graph* g = (graph*)malloc(sizeof(graph) + (nVertices * sizeof(node)));
    g->nVertices = nVertices;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nVertices; i++) {
        node* z = new_node(-1);
        g->heads[i] = *z;
    }
    return g;
}

void add_node_to_graph(graph* g, int data) {
    node* z = new_node(data);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < g->nVertices; i++) {
        if (g->heads[i].data < 0) {
            g->heads[i] = *z;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int in_graph_head_list(graph* g, int data) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < g->nVertices; i++) {
        if (g->heads[i].data == data)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void AddEdges(graph* g, int source, int dest, int time, int distance, int cost) {
    if (!in_graph_head_list(g, source)) {
        add_node_to_graph(g, source);
    }
    if (!in_graph_head_list(g, dest)) {
        add_node_to_graph(g, dest);
    }
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < g->nVertices; i++) {
        if (g->heads[i].data == source) {
            int indexDest = -1;
            for (j = 0; j < g->nVertices; j++) {
                if (g->heads[j].data == dest) {
                    indexDest = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (indexDest != -1) {
                list_node* n = new_list_node(indexDest, time, distance, cost);
                if (g->heads[i].head == NULL) {
                    g->heads[i].head = n;
                }
                else {
                    list_node* temp = g->heads[i].head;
                    while (temp->next != NULL) {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next = n;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void printgraph(graph* g) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < g->nVertices; i++) {
        node* curr_node = &(g->heads[i]);
        printf("Node %d: ", curr_node->data);
        list_node* temp = curr_node->head;
        if (temp == NULL) {
            printf("No adjacent nodes.\n");
        }
        else {
            while (temp != NULL) {
                int adjacent_vertex = g->heads[temp->index].data;
                printf("%d (T=%d, D=%d, C=%d)", adjacent_vertex, temp->time, temp->distance, temp->cost);
                temp = temp->next;
                if (temp != NULL) {
                    printf(" --> ");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void print_updated_graph(graph* g) {
    printf("Updated Graph:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < g->nVertices; i++) {
        node* curr_node = &(g->heads[i]);
        printf("Node %d: ", curr_node->data);
        list_node* temp = curr_node->head;
        if (temp == NULL) {
            printf("No adjacent nodes.\n");
        } else {
            while (temp != NULL) {
                int adjacent_vertex = g->heads[temp->index].data;
                printf("%d (T=%d, D=%d, C=%d)", adjacent_vertex, temp->time, temp->distance, temp->cost);
                temp = temp->next;
                if (temp != NULL) {
                    printf(" --> ");
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
void eliminate_edges(graph* g, int current, int next_vertex, int choice, int* edge_values) {
    node* curr_node = &(g->heads[current - 1]); // Adjusted for 0-based indexing
    list_node* temp = curr_node->head;
    list_node* prev = NULL;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        int adjacent_vertex = temp->index + 1; // Adjusted for 1-based indexing

        // Check if the adjacent vertex is not the next_vertex
        if (adjacent_vertex != next_vertex + 1) {
            // Check the chosen weight for elimination
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: // Time
                    if (temp->time >= edge_values[0]) {
                        if (prev == NULL) {
                            curr_node->head = temp->next;
                        } else {
                            prev->next = temp->next;
                        }
                        free(temp);
                    } else {
                        prev = temp;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: // Distance
                    if (temp->distance > edge_values[1]) { // Use > instead of >=
                        if (prev == NULL) {
                            curr_node->head = temp->next;
                        } else {
                            prev->next = temp->next;
                        }
                        free(temp);
                    } else {
                        prev = temp;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3: // Cost
                    if (temp->cost >= edge_values[2]) {
                        if (prev == NULL) {
                            curr_node->head = temp->next;
                        } else {
                            prev->next = temp->next;
                        }
                        free(temp);
                    } else {
                        prev = temp;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


void find_path(graph* g, int current, int end, int* visited, int* path, int path_length, int choice) {
    visited[current] = 1;
    path[path_length] = current;
    path_length++;

    if (current == end) {
        // Found a path from start to end
        printf("Path: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < path_length - 1; i++) {
            printf("%d ", path[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", path[path_length - 1]);

        // Print edge values
        for (int i = 0; i < path_length - 1; i++) {
            node* curr_node = &(g->heads[path[i] - 1]);
            list_node* temp = curr_node->head;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                if (temp->index + 1 == path[i + 1]) {
                    printf("Edge (%d, %d): (T=%d, D=%d, C=%d)\n", path[i], path[i + 1], temp->time, temp->distance, temp->cost);
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        node* curr_node = &(g->heads[current - 1]); // Adjusted for 0-based indexing
        list_node* temp = curr_node->head;
        int next_vertex = temp->index + 1; // Adjusted for 1-based indexing
        int* path_visited = calloc(g->nVertices + 1, sizeof(int)); // Array to track visited vertices within the current path
        int multiple_paths = 0; // Variable to track multiple paths
        int edge_values[3] = { INT_MAX, INT_MAX, INT_MAX }; // Array to store edge values for comparison
        
        while (temp != NULL) {
            int adjacent_vertex = temp->index + 1; // Adjusted for 1-based indexing
            if (!visited[adjacent_vertex]) {
                if (path_visited[adjacent_vertex]) {
                    multiple_paths = 1;
                    break;
                }
                path_visited[adjacent_vertex] = 1;
                next_vertex++;
                
                // Store edge values for comparison
                if (temp->time < edge_values[0])
                    edge_values[0] = temp->time;
                if (temp->distance < edge_values[1])
                    edge_values[1] = temp->distance;
                if (temp->cost < edge_values[2])
                    edge_values[2] = temp->cost;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // Check if there are multiple paths from the current vertex to the next adjacent vertex
        if (multiple_paths) {
            eliminate_edges(g, current, next_vertex, choice, edge_values);
        }

        temp = curr_node->head; // Reset the temp pointer

        while (temp != NULL) {
            int adjacent_vertex = temp->index + 1; // Adjusted for 1-based indexing
            if (!visited[adjacent_vertex]) {
                find_path(g, adjacent_vertex, end, visited, path, path_length, choice);
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        free(path_visited);
    }

    visited[current] = 0;
    path_length--;
}


int main() {
    graph* g = new_graph(4);
    printf("Welcome to the trip graph.\n");
    printf("The trip roads are as below.\n\n");
    AddEdges(g, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1);
    AddEdges(g, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1);
    AddEdges(g, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5);
    AddEdges(g, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1);
    AddEdges(g, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3);
    AddEdges(g, 3, 1, 7, 1, 4);
    AddEdges(g, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2);
    AddEdges(g, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1);
    AddEdges(g, 3, 4, 1, 7, 6);
    AddEdges(g, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2);
    AddEdges(g, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1);
    AddEdges(g, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5);

    printgraph(g);
    int start, end;
    while (1) {
        printf("\nEnter your starting Node for elimination (press -1 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &start);
        if (start == -1) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter the ending node: ");
        scanf("%d", &end);
        int choice;
        while (1) {
            printf("\nBased on what do you want to do the elimination?\n");
            printf("1. Time 2. Distance 3. Cost\n");
    
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            printf("\nAll paths from %d to %d:\n", start, end);
            if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 3) {
                break;
            } else {
                printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
            }
            
        }

        int* visited = calloc(g->nVertices + 1, sizeof(int)); // Array to track visited vertices
        int* path = calloc(g->nVertices + 1, sizeof(int)); // Array to store the current path
        find_path(g, start, end, visited, path, 0, choice);

        free(visited);
        free(path);
        print_updated_graph(g); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have modified the question. I would be grateful if you can help me out.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't quite complete: no library headers, no definition of `graph` etc. and many absent functions. It still isn't clear what the question is about C, apart from "my code does not work".

Comment: Sorry I thought it might be redundant as the code is long. I have written the whole code right now. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: Are you asking for algorithms or debugging techniques? Is this code still using Dijkstra? If not, what? Reduce the data set to very simple examples that you can figure out by hand, and use the debugger to follow what you expect to happen.

Comment: I have used this algorithm but could not get an answer what algorithms do you suggest me to use for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem:

- Define a structure that contains information about an edge.
- Declare and initialize an array of those structures.
- Sort the array first by source, then by destination, then by the value that the user has chosen.
- Then go through the array, and only call `addEdge` for those edges that the user has chosen. When adding an edge to the graph, the weight for the edge is the parameter chosen by the user.
- Now you have a simple graph with only a single edge between any given source and destination, and you can apply the path-finding algorithm to the graph.

The code below demonstrates these concepts. The `addEdge` function simply prints the chosen edges, rather than adding them to the graph. The full code would add the edges to the graph, find the best path, and then print the results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { SORT_BY_TIME, SORT_BY_DISTANCE, SORT_BY_COST, INVALID_CHOICE };

typedef struct Edge
{
    int source;
    int dest;
    int time;
    int distance;
    int cost;
} Edge;

int compareEdges(const Edge *edge1, const Edge *edge2, int choice)
{
    // if the sources are different, the edge with the lower source index is first
    if (edge1->source != edge2->source)
        return (edge1->source > edge2->source) - (edge1->source < edge2->source);

    // if the destinations are different, the edge with the lower destination index is first
    if (edge1->dest != edge2->dest)
        return (edge1->dest > edge2->dest) - (edge1->dest < edge2->dest);

    // otherwise sort based on the user-selected criteria
    switch (choice)
    {
        case SORT_BY_TIME:     return (edge1->time > edge2->time) - (edge1->time < edge2->time);
        case SORT_BY_DISTANCE: return (edge1->distance > edge2->distance) - (edge1->distance < edge2->distance);
        case SORT_BY_COST:     return (edge1->cost > edge2->cost) - (edge1->cost < edge2->cost);
        default:               return 0; // should never happen, but the compiler needs this
    }
}

int compareByTime(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    return compareEdges(ptr1, ptr2, SORT_BY_TIME);
}

int compareByDistance(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    return compareEdges(ptr1, ptr2, SORT_BY_DISTANCE);
}

int compareByCost(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    return compareEdges(ptr1, ptr2, SORT_BY_COST);
}

int getUserChoice(void)
{
    printf("\nBased on what do you want to do the elimination?\n");
    printf("1. Time 2. Distance 3. Cost\n");
    int choice;
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
        return INVALID_CHOICE;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: return  SORT_BY_TIME;
        case 2: return  SORT_BY_DISTANCE;
        case 3: return  SORT_BY_COST;
        default: return INVALID_CHOICE;
    }
}

void addEdge(Edge *edge, int choice)
{
    // print the source, destination, and chosen weight
    // in the full code, this would add the source, destination, and weight to the graph
    switch (choice)
    {
        case SORT_BY_TIME:      printf("%d->%d: %d\n", edge->source, edge->dest, edge->time);       break;
        case SORT_BY_DISTANCE:  printf("%d->%d: %d\n", edge->source, edge->dest, edge->distance);   break;
        case SORT_BY_COST:      printf("%d->%d: %d\n", edge->source, edge->dest, edge->cost);       break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    static Edge edgeList[] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 3, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 4, 1, 4, 5 },
        { 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 },
        { 2, 1, 2, 1, 3 },
        { 3, 1, 7, 1, 4 },
        { 3, 1, 1, 3, 2 },
        { 3, 4, 4, 3, 1 },
        { 3, 4, 1, 7, 6 },
        { 4, 4, 5, 3, 2 },
        { 4, 3, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 4, 2, 1, 4, 5 },
    };
    int edgeCount = sizeof(edgeList) / sizeof(edgeList[0]);

    while (1)
    {
        int choice = getUserChoice();

        // sort the edges based on the user's choice
        switch (choice)
        {
            case SORT_BY_TIME:      qsort(edgeList, edgeCount, sizeof(Edge), compareByTime);     break;
            case SORT_BY_DISTANCE:  qsort(edgeList, edgeCount, sizeof(Edge), compareByDistance); break;
            case SORT_BY_COST:      qsort(edgeList, edgeCount, sizeof(Edge), compareByCost);     break;
            default: printf("bye\n"); exit(1);
        }

        // add the chosen edges to the graph 
        addEdge(&edgeList[0], choice);
        int used = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < edgeCount; i++)
            if (edgeList[i].source != edgeList[used].source || (edgeList[i].source == edgeList[used].source && edgeList[i].dest != edgeList[used].dest))
            {
                addEdge(&edgeList[i], choice);
                used = i;
            }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample run of the program. Note that only edges `3->1` and `3->4` have multiple edges to choose from. I've highlighted those with comments.

```
Based on what do you want to do the elimination?
1. Time 2. Distance 3. Cost
1
1->2: 1
1->3: 1
2->1: 2
2->3: 3
2->4: 1
3->1: 1   // best time for 3->1 is 1
3->4: 1   // best time for 3->4 is 1
4->2: 1
4->3: 1
4->4: 5

Based on what do you want to do the elimination?
1. Time 2. Distance 3. Cost
2
1->2: 1
1->3: 1
2->1: 1
2->3: 2
2->4: 4
3->1: 1   // best distance for 3->1 is 1
3->4: 3   // best distance for 3->4 is 3
4->2: 4
4->3: 1
4->4: 3

Based on what do you want to do the elimination?
1. Time 2. Distance 3. Cost
3
1->2: 1
1->3: 1
2->1: 3
2->3: 1
2->4: 5
3->1: 2   // best cost for 3->1 is 2
3->4: 1   // best cost for 3->1 is 1
4->2: 5
4->3: 1
4->4: 2

Based on what do you want to do the elimination?
1. Time 2. Distance 3. Cost
4
bye
```

---

Notes about indexing:

- convert from 1-based indexing to 0-based indexing in `addEdge`
- convert from 0-based indexing to 1-based indexing in `printGraph`
- all of the path-finding code should be using 0-based indexing.

In my code, the `addEdge` function *is* doing the printing, so there are no conversions anywhere in the code.